# Silverlight WCF Authentication (Help going from WPF to Silverlight)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ssl, silverlight-2.0, wcf-security

I have an existing working WPF Application in which I have implemented my own custom authentication to a backend WCF service. When I access this service from WPF, setup the ServiceProxy as follows:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

and because I'm using HTTPS the uid/pwd is secure.

In Silverlight 2 there is no .ClientCredentials object on the proxy. The only option I've found is to add two string parameters to EVERY WCF Exposed method for Uid/Pwd. That sounds like insanity to me, there MUST be a better way, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Silverlight 2 only supports basicHttpBinding which means it doesn't support ClientCredentials.

The 2 options you have are:
1. As you mentioned passing the username and pass with each request.
2. using asp.net authentication and enable asp.net compatability mode in your services.

***-- N.B TransportSecurityWithMessageCredentials I mention below didn't seem to make the cut for SL3 so only options are the 2 above for both SL2 and SL3***

Silverlight 3 improves on this story with TransportSecurityWithMessageCredentials and you can find out more about this on the Silverlight Web Services Team blog (Would link to it but apparently as I'm a new user I'm not allowed0

HTH

Comment: Do you have a link to using asp.net authentication through silverlight 2?

Does Transport SecurityWithmessageCredentials provide roughly the same thing as ClientCredentials in WPF?

Comment: For asp.net compat mode essentially all you need to do is decorate your wcf classes with  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

You then get access to HttpContext which means you can access the User properties populated by the asp.net membership. Helpful link I found was http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/05/03/accessing-the-asp-net-authentication-profile-and-role-service-in-silverlight.aspx

Can't comment on the similarities for TransportSecurityWithMessageCredentials as not had a chance to play with it yet. 

HTH