# Integrated Windows Authentication in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, windows-authentication

I understand it was not possible to use Windows Integrated Authentication in Silverlight 2.

(See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885326/silverlight-wcf-authentication-help-going-from-wpf-to-silverlight)).

Does anybody know whether it's possible in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not, the authentication options in SL3 are the same as I mention in the related question you link to and TransportSecurityWithMessageCredentials I mentioned didn't seem to make the cut for SL3 rtw afaik which is a shame

Comment: @Andy - Thanks for that. Maybe you should update your related answer, now that Silverlight 3 has been released and there's concrete information.